# How to handle-escape both single and double quotes in an SQL-Update statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have this sample T-SQL query and trying this on SQL-Server-2008.

```
DECLARE nvarchar(1000) @wstring = "I asked my son's teacher, "How is my son doing now?"" 

UPDATE tablename SET columnname = ' " & @wstring & " ' where ... blah ... blah
```

I know that the above query will throw error.

So how do I  handle-escape both single and double quotes in an SQL-Update statement.

Comment: Is the situation that you have a particular text file you want to insert manually in the SQL client? Or are you writing a program to insert the file, and you're just testing it in the client to figure out how to write the program?

Comment: Thx Russell... for trying to understand the situation. The scenario is like -- there are various systems that send us this 1000+ characters string. Now this string is passed on as a sql-parameter and my sql update-query needs to insert string this into a particular column.

Comment: At the point where it is a 1000+ char string, BEFORE it becomes a SQL parameter, perform the subsitution.  Use whatever tool is appropriate, command-line grep, C#, etc., just use whatever find-replace functionality is available before the 1000+ char string becomes SQL.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a SQL question.  It's more of a systems integration question.

Answer (score 35):

You can escape the quotes with a backslash:

```
"I asked my son's teacher, \"How is my son doing now?\""
```

Comment: I have already said that manually adding a 'slash \' or a single-quote before every quote and alike for double-quote is impratcial and ruled out, because the above example is just a sample one and the actual application value is more than 1000 characters.

Answer (score 26):

Use two single quotes to escape them in the sql statement.  The double quotes should not be a problem:

```
SELECT 'How is my son''s school helping him learn?  "Not as good as Stack Overflow would!"'
```

Print:

`How is my son's school helping him learn?  "Not as good as Stack Overflow would!"`

Comment: Thanks Mike.  BUT I have already said that manually adding a 'slash \' or a single-quote before every quote and alike for double-quote is impractcal and ruled out, because the above example is just a sample one and the actual application value is more than 1000 characters.

Comment: If escaping the characters is impractical, then I imagine that it is going to be pretty difficult to escape them.  Alternatively, you can try determining a substitute value for the ", and batch-replace them so you can execute your query.  Of course, you will then also have to re-replace them to the correct values when you needed them to be displayed.

Comment: Ya Mike.. I did think something to that extent... about a batch-replace and alike.  BUT I feel that would be a overkill for this scenario and SQL must have some inherent elegant way of handling this, because this problem would have been existent 10 yrs before as well.

Comment: Ironic that Stack Overflow teaches kids to learn good, but not to learn well :|

Answer (score 4):

When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF, literal strings in expressions can be delimited by single or double quotation marks.

**If a literal string is delimited by double quotation marks, the string can contain embedded single quotation marks, such as apostrophes.**

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what language you are programming in, you can use a function to replace double quotes with two double quotes.

For example in PHP that would be:

```
str_replace('"', '""', $string);
```

If you are trying to do that using SQL only, maybe [REPLACE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) is what you are looking for.

So your query would look something like this:

```
"UPDATE Table SET columnname = '" & REPLACE(@wstring, '"', '""') & "' where ... blah ... blah "
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# and VB the SqlCommand object implements the Parameter.AddWithValue method which 
handles this situation

Answer (score 0):

Use "REPLACE" to remove special characters.

```
REPLACE(ColumnName ,' " ','')
```

Ex: -

--Query ---

```
DECLARE @STRING AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @STRING ='VI''RA""NJA "'

SELECT @STRING 
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@STRING,'''',''),'"','') AS MY_NAME
```

--Result---

VI'RA""NJA"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar problem by first importing the text into an excel spreadsheet, then using the Substitute function to replace both the single and double quotes as required by SQL Server, eg. `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "'", "''"), """", "\""")`

In my case, I had many rows (each a line of data to be cleaned then inserted) and had the spreadsheet automatically generate insert queries for the text once the substitution had been done eg.   =`"INSERT INTO [dbo].[tablename] ([textcolumn]) VALUES ('" &  SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "'", "''"), """", "\""") & "')"`

I hope that helps.