# How to save XAML on SQL database in c#

Tags: c#, sql, xaml

I have xaml tags. 
I need to save it on the SQL database table.
That table contains following columns.

Documents(ID : int, XAMLDocument :Data Type)

Comment: Use either `nvarchar`, `varchar` or `xml` data type and `INSERT` command - or what answer do you expect...? Not clear at all.

Comment: can use nvarchar or varchar, but xaml routines contains the double quotations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8930229/2224701

Comment: Thanx Vojtech. It's can save as XML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle-escape both single and double quotes in an SQL-Update statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930151/how-to-handle-escape-both-single-and-double-quotes-in-an-sql-update-statement)